# How to Multiple C# Task Factory

Tags: c#, task

This is the C# Code

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);

CpuEngine cpuEngine = new CpuEngine(1500);
MemoryEngine memoryEngine = new MemoryEngine(1500);
// Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await cpuEngine.StartCpuCheck());
// Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await memoryEngine.StartCheckMemory());
```

Only the first one is running. How can I run each other?

Comment: what happens if you remove the words async and await from both those lines - both should be running

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're currently starting both and then doing nothing with the results.

Comment: Is it possible that your program ends right after this code? Please provide the rest of the code.

Comment: i am using SignalR (Websocket) 
the first line : 
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await cpuEngine.StartCpuCheck()); working fine but the second one not running at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `Task.Run` instead.
2) Remove the keywords `async` and `await` in the lambda.
3) Use `Task.WhenAll` and pass in the two tasks.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync()
{
    var cpuEngine = new CpuEngine(1500);
    var memoryEngine = new MemoryEngine(1500);

    await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => cpuEngine.StartCpuCheck()),
        Task.Run(() => memoryEngine.StartCheckMemory()));        
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Task.Run()` might be "dangerous" in some scenarios, when synchronization context allows only single threaded executions (such as asp.net request context). It could result in runtime exceptions or even corrupted data if not used carefully.